# How to implement some functions in C++ for Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote, package-writing

I implemented some special functions in pure Asymptote language and they are useful. But one recommends me to implement them in C++ instead. I'd like (and I already have these functions in C++) but I don't know where to start, I didn't find any information about the way to make an Asymptote package with C++ functions. Would you have some hints?

Comment: A **healthy** question.